# ui:repeat and p:poll

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a ui:repeat. I want it to refresh for every 5 seconds. I tried p:poll but it doesnt work. Is there any way to make this working?

```
<ui:repeat value="#{videoImpl.fGetAllComments()}" var="v" id="commentlist">
<div class="comment-entry"><h:outputText value="#{v.comment}"/></div>
</ui:repeat>

<p:poll update="commentlist" interval="5" />
```

Comment: You forgot to show your `<p:poll>` attempt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<ui:repeat>` doesn't generate any HTML by itself. So there is no element with `id="commentlist"` in the HTML output and hence the JS code behind `<p:poll>` can't find anything to update.

Wrap it in another JSF component which renders a fullworthy HTML element, such as `<h:panelGroup>`, and update it instead.

```
<h:panelGroup id="commentlist">
    <ui:repeat value="#{videoImpl.fGetAllComments()}" var="v">
        <div class="comment-entry">#{v.comment}</div>
    </ui:repeat>
</h:panelGroup>

<p:poll update="commentlist" interval="5" />
```

Comment: It gives error. ** Poll must be inside a form.** I took both of them in a `<h:form>`. It works now. Thanks

Comment: Surely it must be inside a `<h:form>`. How else would it be able to send an ajax request to JSF side? :)